# make cartesian coordinate with for-loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop

i'm trying to make cartesian coordinate for my coursework and can only get here, I'm grateful if anyone can help me to fix this "0" line

```
<?php
$n=10;
for($i=-10;$i<=$n;$i++){
    for($j=-10;$j<=$n;$j++){
        if($i==0 || $j==0){
            echo " $i ";
        }   else {
                echo "   ";
            }
        
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqYs2.jpg)
[What i expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/607Ns.jpg)

Comment: You only ever echo the one axis value `echo " $i ";`

Comment: You want to do this in console...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in mode console.
But it's not really readable

But the principle is there

```
$n=10;

for($y=$n;$y>-$n;$y--)
{
    for($x=-$n;$x<=$n;$x++)
    {
        $infoDisplay = "  ";

        if($x==0)   $infoDisplay = $y;
        if($y==0)   $infoDisplay = $x;

        echo $infoDisplay;
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: I modify my code to have many positive Ys in the upper part because with the old code the axis was reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You could reserve a grid. "Draw" the axis and print it out.

```
$size = 10;
$grid = array_fill(0, $size * 2 + 1, array_fill(0, $size * 2 + 1, ''));

for ($x = -$size; $x <= $size; ++$x) {
    $grid[$size][$x + $size] = $x;
    $grid[$x + $size][$size] = $x;
}

foreach ($grid as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        $cell === '' ? print '    ' : printf('%+3d ', $cell);
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Output

```
                                        -10                                         
                                         -9                                         
                                         -8                                         
                                         -7                                         
                                         -6                                         
                                         -5                                         
                                         -4                                         
                                         -3                                         
                                         -2                                         
                                         -1                                         
-10  -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1  +0  +1  +2  +3  +4  +5  +6  +7  +8  +9 +10 
                                         +1                                         
                                         +2                                         
                                         +3                                         
                                         +4                                         
                                         +5                                         
                                         +6                                         
                                         +7                                         
                                         +8                                         
                                         +9                                         
                                        +10
```